# Datatable and chart drupal view

Tags: drupal

[image]I decided to use Drupal for a project. I am having some difficulties so please kindly help me.

1. I want to generate a table containing different calculations.
2. I want to generate a chart using the data from the table. If possible.
3. I tried before with view aggregation but no luck so far
4. I can't use google chart . Machine don't have access to internet.

Please see the attached image for info

Comment: It seems all of the chart modules that I have seen use a chart service, which will need internet connection. Maybe you could cache the chart js locally (might also be a good feature request for the drupal chart modules).
Or you could create your own views plugin that uses some other opensource charting library.
http://my.opera.com/tagawa/blog/list-of-javascript-charting-libraries

Comment: I can create with pChart but the current problem is "view" I am planning to create a new table with "View Module". Machines serving as server will locate in rural area with no internet.

Comment: You will need to create your own views plugin module. If you have a good understanding of OOP this should not be too hard. Grab a module that already supplies a views plugin such as views_slideshow and take a look how that module does it.

Comment: thank you all for your kind inputs , I finally decided to write my own using php. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) in combination with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) is for sure an option that does not require an internet connection. However you'd have to check The license terms to see if you qualify for a free license (at no Cost). Refer to [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929) for step by step instructions.

There are some other modules available also, which also facilitate the creation of charts, and which might be considered as a possible alternative to the charts module. Checkout the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) I creatief, for more details about them.